# Parse Server mocking for Testing

Tags: php, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm using Parse server in my php applicaiton,
Now I want to test my php app using phpunit every thing goes well but how I can test or mock Parse server "PHP SDK" in my test case ,Any ideas?!

Comment: It depends on what you're going to test and how your application is set up. Currently, this question is too broad and unspecific. How you mock classes all depends on your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start is to see how unit tests are done in the [parse php sdk](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk).

Rather than mocking parse-server, the sdk spins up a test parse-server with an in memory, empty mongo.

Take a look at the [contributing guide](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) for step by step directions on how to get the tests to run.

Comment: It's great Idea to starting with ,Thanks